# how to prove convexity of $\overline{K} $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K$ be a nonempty convex subset of $R^k$

how to prove convexity of $\overline{K}$?

Comment: What does $\bar x$ mean?

Comment: Part 2 is a form of the Hahn Banach theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** 
Let $x,y \in \overline{K}$, $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $p=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$. We want to show that $p \in \overline{K}$.

To do this, we show that $B(p,\epsilon) \cap K \neq \emptyset$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$. Then let $x' \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap K$, and similarly for $y'$. Let $p'= x'+(1-\lambda)y'$. Clearly $p' \in K$. Furthermore, $|p-p'| = |\lambda(x-x')+(1-\lambda) (y-y')| < \epsilon$, and so $p' \in B(p, \epsilon)$,
hence $B(p,\epsilon) \cap K \neq \emptyset$. Hence $p \in \overline{K}$.

**(2)** This is essentially a form of the Hahn Banach theorem. We need a preliminary lemma.

**Lemma**: Suppose $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed convex set, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\overline{c} \in C$ solves $\min_{c \in C} \|x-c\|$ **iff** $\langle c-\overline{c}, \overline{c}-x \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in C$, as required. (We only need the forward direction here.)

As an aside, we note that the $\min$ always exists. To see this, let $c' \in C$, and note that $\inf_{c \in C} \|x-c\| = \inf_{c \in C \cap \overline{B}(x, \|x-c'\|)} \|x-c\| = \min_{c \in C \cap \overline{B}(x, \|x-c'\|)} \|x-c\|$, since $C \cap \overline{B}(x, \|x-c'\|)$ is compact by Heine Borel.

First suppose $\overline{x} \notin \overline{K}$, hence $\min_{c \in \overline{K}} \|\overline{x}-c\| >0$. Let $\overline{c}$ solve the problem, then the lemma gives $\langle c-\overline{c}, \overline{c}-\overline{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in \overline{K}$. 
Hence $\langle c-\overline{x}, \overline{c}-\overline{x} \rangle = 
\langle c-\overline{c}, \overline{c}-\overline{x} \rangle 
+ \langle \overline{c}-\overline{x}, \overline{c}-\overline{x} \rangle \ge 0$.
Letting  $v=\overline{c}-\overline{x}$ gives $\langle v, c-\overline{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in \overline{K}$. Note that $v \neq 0$ because we assumed $\overline{x} \notin \overline{K}$, hence without loss of generality, we may assume $\|v\| = 1$. This proves the assertion for $\overline{x} \notin \overline{K}$.

Now suppose $\overline{x} \in \overline{K}$. By assumption, $\overline{x} \notin K^\circ$, hence $B(\overline{x}, \epsilon)$ has a non empty intersection with $\overline{K}^c$ for all $\epsilon>0$. So choose $x_n \in B(\overline{x}, \frac{1}{n}) \setminus \overline{K}$ for all $n$. Clearly $x_n \to \overline{x}$.

The above reasoning shows that there exists some $v_n$ with $\|v_n\| = 1$ so that $\langle v_n, c-x_n \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in \overline{K}$. Since the set of unit vectors is compact, we have $v_{n_k} \to \overline{v}$ over some subsequence. Taking limits, we see that $\langle \overline{v}, c-\overline{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in \overline{K}$. Hence the assertion is true for all $\overline{x} \notin K^\circ$.

**Proof of lemma**: Suppose $\overline{c} \in C$ solves $\min_{c \in C} \|x-c\|$. Then $\|x-\overline{c}\|^2 \le \|x-c\|^2$ for all $c \in C$. 
Now expand $\|x-c\|^2 = \| x- \overline{c} + \overline{c} -c \|^2 = \| x- \overline{c}  \|^2 + \| \overline{c} -c \|^2 + 2 \langle x- \overline{c} , \overline{c} -c \rangle $, which gives $\| \overline{c} -c \|^2 + 2 \langle x- \overline{c} , \overline{c} -c \rangle \ge 0 $ for all $c \in C$. Now let $\lambda \in [0,1]$, and $c' = \lambda c + (1-\lambda) \overline{c}$, since $c' \in C$, the inequality gives $\lambda^2 \| \overline{c} -c \|^2 + 2 \lambda \langle x- \overline{c} , \overline{c} -c \rangle \ge 0 $ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Dividing by $\lambda >0$, and letting $\lambda \to 0$ gives the required result.

Now for the opposite direction (not required, but just for completeness sake). Suppose $\langle c-\overline{c}, \overline{c}-x \rangle \ge 0$ for all $c \in C$. Then expanding $\|x-c\|^2 $ as above gives 
$\|x-c\|^2  \ge \| x- \overline{c}  \|^2 + \| \overline{c} -c \|^2 \ge  \| x- \overline{c}  \|^2$, from which the result follows.

Comment: Hmmm...I suppose I'm not understanding exactly how $x\mapsto\overline x$ is defined. Can you clarify?

Comment: @CameronBuie: It is just any point $\notin K^\circ$.

Comment: +1: Ah! The word "defined" threw me. I was thinking it was an operator of some sort.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Yes, it is worded badly. I just recognized the threads of a separation theorem... Also, I assume that the idea was to prove the result without the Hahn Banach theorem. Otherwise I just wasted some prime Netflix time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what $\overline{x}$ means, but I can help with the first question.

Take $x,y\in\overline K.$ Then there exist sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ of points of $K$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$. (Why?) Take any $0<a<1,$ let $z=ax+(1-a)y,$ and let $z_n=ax_n+(1-a)y_n$ for all $n$. Since each $x_n,y_n\in K,$ then by convexity, each $z_n\in K$. Since $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y,$ then $z_n\to z,$ so since each $z_n\in K,$ then $z\in\overline K.$

Comment: No, it can be outside $\overline{K}$.

Answer (score 1):

A more geometric argument for the closure proposition (proof outline only).

Let $p,q\in \bar K$ and let $m$ be a point between them not in $\bar K$.

Then there is an open ball $B_m$ about $m$ of radius $r_m$ that does not intersect $K$. Since $p,q\in \bar K$, there are points $p'$ and $q'$ in $K$ whose distances from $p$ and $q$, respectively, are sufficiently small compared to $r_m$ that they can't possibly see each other around $B_m$.